# P-Invoke Unmarshalling an array of structs allocated in a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, c, pinvoke

I have a requirement to shovel large amounts (theoretically up to a few terabytes, only limited by available memory) of data from a C/C++ based core DLL which manages, filters and allocates the data, to a C# GUI (which only reads the data). It would be optimal if the data are never duplicated but only accessed per reference from the C#. The signature of my DLL's method is currently the following (I can make changes there):

```
extern "C" {

typedef struct {
    wchar_t* name;
    __int32 t;
    float v;
    bool condition;

    } TestData;

__declspec(dllexport) void fillTestArrayWithAlloc(TestData** td, __int32* size);
};
```

The array length is not known to C# and can be anything between 1 and millions....

I mapped the structure like this:

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   struct TestData
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public String name;
        public Int32 t;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        public float v; 
        public bool condition;

    }
```

I tried both manual unmarshalling like this

```
static extern void fillTestArrayWithAlloc(ref IntPtr td, ref int size);
```

and automatic unmarshalling like this

```
static extern void fillTestArrayWithAlloc([Out] TestData[] td, ref int size);
```

But in both cases it performs a memory copy, which is undesired. Is there a way to do it without a data copy?

Best regards
Petr

Answer (score 1):

The first version of your function declaration should not cause all the data to be copied: only the pointer and length value will be marshalled.

I think you should then be able to implement an iterator or enumerator which marshals one `TestData` structure at a time directly from the unmanaged memory pointed to by the `IntPtr`, using `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. You will need to do some `unsafe` pointer arithmetic to move from one instance to another as you iterate.

This approach should avoid wholesale copying of the entire structure. Good luck.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to go `unsafe`. You can create new `IntPtr` objects based on an offset of the original value to access different elements of the unmanaged array.

Comment: @Adam: In .NET4, yes... there are new static methods Add/Subtract of IntPtr. Was it possible before?

Comment: @Chris: `IntPtr` has `ToInt32` and a constructor that takes an `Int32`, so while the syntax wasn't the most intuitive, yes.

Comment: @Adam: But the `ctor(Int32)` is also `unsafe`

Comment: @Chris: Are you certain about that?

Comment: @Adam: That's what Reflector tells me